# International characters with Java

Tags: java, excel, localization

I am building an app that takes information from java and builds an excel spreadsheet.  Some of the information contains international characters.  I am having an issue when Russian characters, for example, are rendered correctly in Java, but when I send those characters to Excel, they are not rendered properly.  I initially thought the issue was an encoding problem, but I am now thinking that the problem is simply not have the Russian language pack loaded on my Windows 7 machine.

I need to know if there is a way for a Java application to "force" Excel to show international characters.

Thanks

Comment: `I need to know if there is a way for a Java application to "force" Excel to show international characters.` - did you mean that you want Excel to display Russian without Russian fonts? No, that simply is not possible - fonts and font engines translate the byte sequence into the displayed characters. Without a font, you cannot do that in Excel. On a different note, as long as you have Cyrillic fonts available, you should be able to see Cyrillic characters; I believe you are not encoding the data in Excel correctly.

Comment: How do you "send characters to Excel"?

Comment: What library are you using to "send" these characters to Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the file encoding you're using is characters don't show up. Java defaults to platform native encoding (Win-1252 for Windows) instead of UTF-8. You can explicitly set the writers to use UTF-8 or Cyrillic encoding.